# Volume of the symmetric difference between a parallelotope and its translated.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, determinant, volume

Let $A$ be a n-dimensional parallelotope and $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$  a vector. Is there a formula giving the volume of the symmetric difference $A \Delta (v+A)$?

Comment: I have a similar question, can you try to answer? -https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434895/bound-for-volume-difference-between-translated-parallelotopes-formed-between-2-h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overlap (if any) of the two versions of the parallelotope is again a parellelotope $B$, with the same face normals as $A$. The volume of the symmetric difference is just twice the difference of the volumes of $A$ and $B$. How to put that into a formula depends on how the parallelotope is given.

Comment: Thanks! I have a similar question, can you try to answer? -https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434895/bound-for-volume-difference-between-translated-parallelotopes-formed-between-2-h